# Get WebSphere listener port status in your application

Tags: websphere

I'm running an EAR in WebSphere AS 7. I would like to know whether my listener port is running because it would be important to know whether the messages are being consumed.

Can that be done? If not, is there a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't the better way to listen the SIB port.

What you could do is to establish an acknowledgement mechanism, i.e. send a reply for each message consumed through a second destination.

But I think that the concept of asynchronous messaging assumes that if you have sent a message     you can be sure that somebody will be able to receive them or at least that the message will be sent to an exception destination.